# Scala collections: Is there a safe map operation?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Let's say that I have a List (or the values in a Map), and i want to perform an operation on each item. But unfortunately, for whatever reason, this list of values can contain nulls.

```
scala> val players = List("Messi", null, "Xavi", "Iniesta", null)
players: List[java.lang.String] = List(Messi, null, Xavi, Iniesta, null)
```

In order to avoid blowing up with a NPE, i need to do the following:

```
scala> players.filterNot(_ == null ).map(_.toUpperCase)
res84: List[java.lang.String] = List(MESSI, XAVI, INIESTA)
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Ideally something like:

```
players.safeMap(_.toUpperCase)
```

On the [scala-language mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/scala-language/NPy-jkIo9sY), Simon proposed this:

```
players.filter ( null !=).map(_.toUpperCase )
```

which is shorter version of my original take, and as short as you can get without a dedicated method.

Even better, Stefan and Kevin proposed the method withFilter which will return a lazy proxy, so both operations can be merged.

```
players.withFilter ( null !=).map(_.toUpperCase )
```

Comment: If Tuesday is any indication, the players list is not-at-all-type-safe, not to mention that null is to be avoided in Scala ;-)

Comment: This may or may not apply to your use case, however: If you are never going to use the fact that there have been `null` values in that list, I’d suggest you’d remove them once and for all *before* you assign it to `val players`. You’ll never need to think about them afterwards; no `collect`, no implicits, no NPE.

Comment: @Debilski sometimes your calling code might not be well formed. This is particularly true in mixed Java + Scala applications.

Comment: @virtualeyes, the identities of the nulls has been disguised to protect their image :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can’t avoid `null`s (e.g. if you get your list from Java code), another alternative is to use `collect` instead of `map`:

```scala
scala> players.collect { case player if player != null => player.toUpperCase }
res0: List[java.lang.String] = List(MESSI, XAVI, INIESTA)
```

Comment: It has the advantage of doing one pass, so at the moment it seems like a good solution. However, it's slightly longer. Is there anything that would look closer to the safeMap(f) that I propose?

Comment: @fracca - You can `{ case player: String => player.toUpperCase }` if the type annotation is shorter than the null test.  For something to match a type, it can't be `null`.

Comment: @fracca you can avoid two passes using `withFilter`, as in `players.withFilter(null!=).map(_.toUpperCase)`

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this:

```
players flatMap Option map (_.toUpperCase)
```

But that's worse than `collect`. `filter` + `map` is always better done with `collect`.

Comment: hmmm, this doesn't compile with 2.9.1

Comment: @LuigiPlinge Yeah, some problem with type parameters. `players flatMap (Option(_)) map (_.toUpperCase)` works.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert to a list of `Option[String]`:

```
scala> val optionPlayers = players.map(Option(_))
optionPlayers: List[Option[java.lang.String]] = List(Some(Messi), None, Some(Xavi), Some(Iniesta), None)
```

`Option` is universally preferred to `null` and it gives you a lot of flexibility in how you can safely handle the data.  Here's are thee easy ways to get the result you were looking for:

```
scala> optionPlayers.collect { case Some(s) => s.toUpperCase }
res0: List[java.lang.String] = List(MESSI, XAVI, INIESTA)

scala> optionPlayers.flatMap(_.map(_.toUpperCase))
res1: List[java.lang.String] = List(MESSI, XAVI, INIESTA)

scala> optionPlayers.flatten.map(_.toUpperCase)
res2: List[java.lang.String] = List(MESSI, XAVI, INIESTA)
```

You can find a lot more information about `Option` in other StackOverflow questions or by searching the web.

Or, you can always just define that `safeMap` method you wanted as an implicit on `List`:

```
implicit def enhanceList[T](list: List[T]) = new {
  def safeMap[R](f: T => R) = list.filterNot(_ == null).map(f)
}
```

so you can do:

```
scala> players.safeMap(_.toUpperCase)
res4: List[java.lang.String] = List(MESSI, XAVI, INIESTA)
```

Though if you define an implicit, you might want to use a `CanBuildFrom` style like the basic collections do to make it work on more than just `List`.  You can find more information about that elsewhere.

Comment: I would then something all this for the same output:
`val optionPlayers = players.map(Option(_))`
`optionPlayers.map(_.map(_.toUpperCase))`
`optionPlayers.map(_.map(_.toUpperCase)).flatten`

Comment: @fracca, see my suggestions for getting the same output from your question.

Comment: Options are indeed preferrable, however, there are cases where you already have nulls (say, interacting with poorly written Java code). Transforming to Options and then applying the operations is too verbose. I want something really concise that hides all that noise.

Comment: @fracca, See my suggestion about just defining an implicit `safeMap` method.  This will definitely be the cleanest-looking thing in your code.

Comment: i think you are right, the implicit approach is probably the cleanest solution. However, I'm hoping that a solution like this is already defined in the library. A good candidate operation to add to the library perhaps?